# test for nested object in a custom matcher

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, matcher

I would like to test, if a function is called with a specific nested object.

```
myFunction({ variables: { input: { id: 12345, foo: 'bar' }}})
```

So this is my `expect` in the test:

```
expect(myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  expect.objectContaining({
    variables: expect.objectContaining({
      input: expect.objectContaining({
        id: 12345,
        foo: 'bar'
      })
    })
  })
)
```

I like this one as the error message in case of a failing test is very useful.

As I have to test many times for the object, I would like to extract the `toHaveBeenCalledWith` into a own function or even better build a custom matcher.

Just putting the repeatable part into a own function is not correct:

```
export const parameterFunctionCall = (param: object, name: string = "input"): void => {
  expect.objectContaining({
    variables: expect.objectContaining({
      [name]: expect.objectContaining(param)
    })
  })
}

expect(myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  parameterFunctionCall({
    id: 12345,
    foo: 'bar'
  })
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why is this not working for you? Are you missed this function?

```js
expect(data).toHaveProperty(['variables', 'input', 'foo'], 'bar');
expect(data).toHaveProperty(['variables', 'input', 'id'], 12345);
```

```js
test('test', () => {
    let data = { variables: { input: {id: 12345, foo: 'bar' }}}

    expect(data).toHaveProperty(['variables', 'input', 'id'], 12345)
    expect(data).toHaveProperty(['variables', 'input', 'foo'], 'bar')

    let f = jest.fn(() => true)
    f(data)

    expect(f).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data)
})
```

If you don't want to use this function, I made a recursive function for you.

```js
let data = { variables: { input: {id: 12345, foo: 'bar' }}}

const nestedCheckerRecursive = (data, arr, iteration) => {
    if (arr.length == iteration) return

    expect(data[arr[iteration].propName])[arr[iteration].method](arr[iteration].data)

    nestedCheckerRecursive(data[arr[iteration].propName], arr, iteration + 1)
}

test('test', () => {
    nestedCheckerRecursive(data, [
        {
            propName: "variables",
            method: "toBeDefined"
        },
        {
            propName: "input",
            method: "toBeDefined"
        },
        {
            propName: "id",
            method: "toEqual",
            data: 12345
        }
    ], 0)
});
```

Maybe I misunderstood your question. idk

Comment: I need to test the parameter passed by calling the method. So I have to use `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()`. I dont see, how to use `toHaveProperty` inside of this.

Comment: I edited my answer. Actually, you don't need call to `objectContaining` function, you must check the parameter before and pass.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the return value of `parameterFunctionCall`. `void` is not compliant with the signature of [`toHaveBeenCalledWith`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/fdc74af37235354e077edeeee8aa2d1a4a863032/packages/expect/src/spyMatchers.ts#L548):

```
function (
    this: MatcherState,
    received: any,
    ...expected: Array<unknown>
): SyncExpectationResult { ... }
```

In your case this means that, instead of `void`, you should return an instance of [`ObjectContaining`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/expect/src/asymmetricMatchers.ts#L243), simply like this:

```
export const parameterFunctionCall = (param: object, name: string = "input") => {
  return expect.objectContaining({
    variables: expect.objectContaining({
      [name]: expect.objectContaining(param)
    })
  })
}
```

Think about it, if you do not return anything from `parameterFunctionCall`, how could `toHaveBeenCalledWith` know what to match against?
Moreover, I do not see any other problem in what you have written (but I am definitely not an expert on TS).